# Не работает clearInterval

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

```
const Timer = () => {
  var timerId = 0;
  let [timer, setTimer] = useState(10);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (timer === 0) {
      clearInterval(timerId);
    }
  }, [timer]);

  timerId = setInterval(updateCoutDown, 1000);
  function updateCoutDown() {
    setTimer((timer = timer - 1));
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{timer}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Проблема заключается в том что clearInterval не работает. Читал похожие проблемы, ничего не помогло

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`clearInterval` - работает. Просто запускается много `setInterval`, а останавливается только один.

Чтобы запускался только один, его можно запускать внутри `useEffect` с пустым массивом зависимостей.

В этом случае, однако, id таймера нужно хранить в стейте, чтобы можно было остановить его не только в момент выгрузки компонента

```js
const {
  useState,
  useEffect
} = React;
const Timer = () => {
  var [timerId, setTimerId] = useState(0);
  let [timer, setTimer] = useState(10);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (timer === 0) {
      clearInterval(timerId);
      console.log('timer stop');
    }
  }, [timer, timerId]);

  useEffect(() => {
    let internalTimerId = setInterval(updateCoutDown, 1000);

    function updateCoutDown() {
      setTimer(prev => prev - 1);
      console.log('timer hit');
    }
    setTimerId(internalTimerId)
    return () => clearInterval(internalTimerId);
  }, [])
  return ( <
    div >
    <
    h1 > {
      timer
    } < /h1> <
    /div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(root).render( < Timer / > )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так. У Вас переменная `timerId` - постоянно обнулялась и соответсвенно была проблема. Код немного поправил

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, useRef} from 'react';    

const Timer = () => {
  const timerId = useRef();
  const [timer, setTimer] = useState(10);

  useEffect(()=>{
     timerId.current = setInterval(() => 
         setTimer(prev => prev-1)
     , 1000);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (timer === 0) {
      clearInterval(timerId.current);
    }
  }, [timer]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{timer}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: попробовал, не работает(

Comment: ошибка? У меня нет возможности проверить сейчас. Если ошибка напишите сюда

Answer (score -1):

Замечания:

- Не стоит использовать `var`, вместо него используйте `let`
- **НИ В КОЕМ СЛУЧАЕ** не мутируйте стейт компонента. Чтобы избежать такого рода ошибок стейты объявляют через `const`, а не `let`
- Если внутри `useEffect`-а используете таймеры, то не забывайте прописывать очищение таймера при удалении компонента

Решения:

1. На самом деле в вашей задаче нет никакой нужды в `setInterval`-е. Задача намного легче решается если использовать `setTimeout`:

   1. Пишем `useEffect`, который будет слушать `timer`
   2. Внутри него каждый раз объявляем новый `setTimeout`, который очищаем сразу при достижении `0`

   Плюс такого подхода в том, что нам не нужно думать об очищении таймера после каждой секунды. Мы следим только за `timer`-ом

   ```js
   const {useState, useEffect} = React;

   const Timer = () => {
     const [timer, setTimer] = useState(10);
     
     useEffect(() => {
       const timerId = setTimeout(updateCountDown, 1000);
       
       if (timer === 0) clearTimeout(timerId);
       
       return () => clearTimeout(timerId);
     }, [timer]);
     
     function updateCountDown() {
       setTimer(timer => timer - 1);
     }
     
     return (
       <div>
         <h1>{timer}</h1>
       </div>
     );
   };

   ReactDOM.createRoot(root).render(<Timer />);
   ```

   ```html
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
   <div id="root"></div>
   ```
2. Если вам всё же необходимо использовать именно `setInterval`, тогда можно сделать так:

   1. Объявляем `timerId` с помощью `useRef`, потому что нам не нужно будет его менять между перерисовками. Всё что нам нужно - это сохранить идентификатор таймера даже после перерисовки
   2. Пишем `useEffect`, который запустим лишь один раз - при монтировании компонента. Таким образом мы избегам случая, когда у нас создаётся множество таймеров
   3. Далее остаётся лишь проверять наш счётчик. При достижении `0` мы очищаем таймер

   ```js
   const {useState, useEffect, useRef} = React;

   const Timer = () => {
     const timerId = useRef(null);
     const [timer, setTimer] = useState(10);
     
     useEffect(() => {
       timerId.current = setInterval(updateCountDown, 1000);
       
       return () => clearTimeout(timerId.current);
     }, []);
     
     if (timer === 0) clearTimeout(timerId.current);
     
     function updateCountDown() {
       setTimer(timer => timer - 1);
     }
     
     return (
       <div>
         <h1>{timer}</h1>
       </div>
     );
   };

   ReactDOM.createRoot(root).render(<Timer />);
   ```

   ```html
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
   <div id="root"></div>
   ```

Comment: есть небольшая разница запустить один интервал или много раз таймаут, поэтому нельзя однозначно сказать что лучше/легче использовать таймаут. В примере с setTimeout - не надо лишний раз создавать таймер и сразу его останавливать, когда переменная уже 0

Comment: в примере с интервалом проверка `if (timer === 0)` происходит каждый рендер, даже есть таймер не поменялся

Comment: @Grundy да, можно не создавать лишний таймаут. На счёт простоты - я имел ввиду в понимании, т.е. легче в каждой отрисовке следить за одним таймаутом, чем в каждом рендере за интервалом. А так, конечно, между ними есть разница. На счёт второго, я специально не стал писать `useEffect` т.к. операция ничего не стоит. Как по мне `useEffect` сам дороже обойдётся со своими внутренними проверками, чем то что я оставил :)